# Simple XML parser get null

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

i have a problem with parsing XML file by SimpleXml + Retrofit

I get xml file from here by Retrofit
http://www.gdacs.org/xml/rss_eq_48h_low.xml

Response Classes

```js
@Root(name = "rss", strict = false)
public class EarthQuakeResponse {
    @Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
    public Channel channel;

    public class Channel {
        @ElementList
        public List<EarthQuake> earthquakes;
    }
}
```

```js
@Element(name = "item")
public class EarthQuake {
    @Element(name = "title")
    public String title;

    @Element(name = "description")
    public String description;

    @Element(name = "pubDate")
    public String pubDate;

    @Element(name = "georss:point")
    public String point;
}
```

But once i get the reponse, the channel value is null , neither the EarthQuake List

Please help or point out which did i do wrong.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Root(name = "rss", strict = false)
    public class EarthQuakeResponse {
        @Element(name = "channel")
        public Channel channel;

    }
    @Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
    public class Channel {
            @ElementList
            public List<EarthQuake> earthquakes;
        }
```